# How to change DWORD registry entry with .BAT file

Tags: batch-file, registry, regedit

I wanted to change the entry LockedStartLayout from 1 to 0. From what I've researched the following in a .bat file should do the trick:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer" /v LockedStartLayout /t DWORD /d "0" /f
```

However, it is not working, so I assume I am doing something wrong. Is this something simple I am missing out on, or am I going about this in the wrong direction. I am wanting do change this on several computers so I don't want to make the change individually to each computer. This is being done on W10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax uses `REG_DWORD`:

```
REG ADD HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer /v LockedStartLayout /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

In Windows 7 and higher, you have to run it from an elevated shell.

To apply on several machines, do a loop and prefix the machine name in the `reg add` command:

```
for %%i in (machine1 machine2 machine3) do REG ADD \\%%i\HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer /v LockedStartLayout /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

You have to be a domain administrator to be able to do this.